# Convert value from specific multidimensional array key into key in new array with original arrays as value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Basically I just would like to know if there is a built-in way of doing this, that might be faster, like maybe with an array_map callback or something:

```
function array_rekey($a, $column)
{
    $array = array();
    foreach($a as $keys) $array[$keys[$column]] = $keys;
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: See also: [Generate an associative array from an array of rows using one column as keys and another column as values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71030583/2943403)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just pass `NULL` as second argument to [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to get the full array back as values and use `$column` as third argument for the keys.

```
$result = array_column($arr, NULL, $column);
```

example input/output:

```
$arr = [
        ["a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3],
        ["a" => 4, "b" => 5, "c" => 6],
        ["a" => 7, "b" => 8, "c" => 9],
    ];

$column = "b";
$result = array_column($arr, NULL, $column);
print_r($result);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 2
            [c] => 3
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [a] => 4
            [b] => 5
            [c] => 6
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [a] => 7
            [b] => 8
            [c] => 9
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I don't have array_column() available on my ded server.

Comment: @Thom You could do a little workaround with `array_combine()` and `array_map()`, like this: `$result = array_combine(
   array_map(function($v)use($column){
    return $v[$column]
   }, $a),
   $a);` OR you can use [`array_column()`](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php) for under php 5.5.

Comment: Nice, didn't know array_column had these hidden arguments.