# Get two columns of data as an array of keys and values using Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5, orm, array-column

What is the Laravel's way to retrieve an associative array in which, the keys are the first column of a query and the values are the second column.

```
User::select('id','type')->unknown();
```

should return:

```
[
2=>'s',  
30=>'t',
32=>'x',
]
```

Comment: Related: [Generate an associative array from an array of rows using one column as keys and another column as values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3690515/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that method exists, but what you could do is use [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column) on the returned associative array to get what you want:

```
$array = User::select( 'type', 'id' )->all();//get array of assoc arrays
$result = array_column($array, 'type', 'id');//column
```

this will return an array using the `id` key in each sub array of `$array` (ie each result/assoc array) as key, and the `type` value as value. So if `$array` looks like this:

```
$array = [
    [
        'id'   => 1,
        'type' => 'a',
    ],
    [
        'id'   => 2,
        'type' => 'b',
    ],
];
```

The result of the `array_column` call will look like this:

```
$result = [
    1 => 'a',
    2 => 'b',
];
```

**Note** `array_column` requires PHP 5.5 or higher, if you're running 5.4, and you can't upgrade, write your own function, it's easy enough:

```
function myArrayCol(array $in, $valKey, $idxKey = null)
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($in as $sub) {
        if (!is_array($sub)) {
            throw new RuntimeException('myArrayCol requires a multi-dimensional array to be passed');
        }
        $value = isset($sub[$valKey]) ? $sub[$valKey] : null;
        if ($idxKey === null || !isset($sub[$idxKey])) P
            $result[] = $value;
        } else {
            $result[$sub[$idxKey]] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Note this implementation is completely untested, but you get the basic idea...

---

### Update

Aparently, laravel does have a method that does what the OP wants, as @Mat suggested, and [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries) show:

```
$result = User::lists('type', 'id')->all();
```

That returns the result the OP is after in a one-liner.

Comment: Thanks. I guess  the first two code blocks should be swap .

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
User::lists( 'type', 'id' )->all();
```

Comment: Read the question, OP wants the keys of the array to be the `id`'s, and the values to be the `type` values in the array. `->all` will return an array of associative arrays

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem No it won't. `lists` does exactly what the OP wants.... your `array_column` stuff is unnecessary. This answer needs more explanation though.

Comment: @andrewtweber: Right you are, didn't notice Mat changed the method that was called. I've updated my answer to include the `lists` method + added a link to the docs. +1 to this answer, though a bit more explanation wouldn't go amiss